# ImageView dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-image, dimensions

I have following **situation**:

I have `ImageView` and `Bitmap` inside it.

**The problem**  is that

- I don't know the dimensions of bitmap (not physical size, size that it takes on screen)

or

- I need `ImageView` not to be bigger that this `Bitmap` on the screen.

`ImageView`'s background has black color on below snapshot.[image]

Comment: You know screenWidth and length-width ratio of Bitmap. So you can get size of bitmap on screen.

Comment: @tinysunlight, Thank you for fast answer. Can you please explain particularly?

Comment: Where are your bitmap and imageview come from?If you just want to clip bitmap,I think using thirdparty library is better.

Comment: Bitmap come from camera intent. I think that solution is so close, but can't find it

Comment: original bitmap size is 960x1260.screenWidth is 900.So bitmap's size on screen is 900x (900*960/1260)

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure the image view isn't bigger than the bitmap by setting its layout_width and layout_height to wrap_content on your imageView tag in its xml file.

You can also use its scaleType to affect how the image should be manipulated to fit the imageView.

You can also just access the bitmap's width/height properties to get its dimensions.

EDIT::

You can convert your bitmap into a byte[] and resize it using the following helpers:

```
/**
 * Resize an image to a specified width and height.
 * @param targetWidth The width to resize to.
 * @param targetHeight The height to resize to.
 * @return The resized image as a Bitmap.
 * */
public static Bitmap resizeImage(byte[] imageData, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap reducedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(reducedBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int requestedWidth, int requestedHeight) {
    // Get the image's raw dimensions
    final int rawHeight = options.outHeight;
    final int rawWidth = options.outWidth;

    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (rawHeight > requestedHeight || rawWidth > requestedWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = rawHeight / 2;
        final int halfWidth = rawWidth / 2;

        /*
        * Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        * height and width larger than their requested counterparts respectively.
        * */
        while ((halfHeight/inSampleSize) > requestedHeight && (halfWidth/inSampleSize) > requestedWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have my ImageView height and width in wrap_content; I don't want to use scaleType because it will deform bitmap. Problem is that original bitmap size is 960x1260. Obviously that bitmap doesn't fill this dimensions on screen (

Comment: Noted and updated answer to show a way to resize bitmap to specified dimensions. If it doesn't fulfill your use requirements, than definitely check out some of the related third party libraries like tiny sunlight said. I personally use Picasso to handle bitmap transformations.